# Web App for Container - Http 503

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, azure-container-registry

I would like to configure continuous integration from VSTS to Azure Container Registry and then to WebApp.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file: As you can see I'm using an Asp.Net core + mssql.

```
version: '3'
    services:
      api:
        image: tbacr.azurecr.io/myservice/api
        container_name: api
        build:
          context: ./Api
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
          - db
      db:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
        container_name: mssql
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "testtest3030!"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
            MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:8001:1433"
```

I have pushed my image using VSTS to Azure Container Registry. 
Here's my Azure Container Registry:
[image]

But when I try to open URI in browser - I get an error message:

---

> Service Unavailable which is HTPP 503 code.

---

Should I configure something more?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only deploy one container to an App Service. You have two images in your docker-compose file. You might consider using either the "Azure SQL Database" or the "Azure Database for MySQL" if you need a database.

You can set up continuous deployment of a custom image from your Azure Container Registry by right clicking the tag of an image in the repository and choose "deploy to web app". Every time you update the image also the web app will be updated.

If you want to deploy Microservices use Service Fabric, Azure Container Service (ACS) or Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

PS: You have uploaded the image of the App Service, not of the Container Registry.